# Trouble installing CDB debugger on Windows 10

Tags: windows, debugging, installation

I'm returning to C programming after a few years of not doing it, and trying to get a debugger set up on my Windows 10 laptop. The whole first page of results on my google search for "windows debugger" eventually lead to the Windows SDK download (which is fine, since CDB is what I used in school).

I downloaded the latest release and ran the installer, and unchecked every box except the "debug tools" one - that's all I want. When I tried to test it I found that cdb wasn't in the path. I searched my entire drive to find out where it was installed, but there's no cdb.exe anywhere on my computer. When I try to run the installer again, it says I have to uninstall the SDK before I can re-run it, but as far as I can tell there's nothing to uninstall. I can't find any trace of the SDK on my computer.

Has anyone had this this problem/know what to do? I can provide more information if needed but I'm yet not sure what info would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that the debuggers are added to the PATH by default; I had to add them myself. But since you installed them through the Windows 10 SDK, they should be here or at least around here:

- 32-bit systems: `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\{architecture}`
- 64-bit systems: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\{architecture}`

where {architecture} is one of:

- `x86`
- `x64`
- `arm`

Add one of those to your PATH and you should be able to get cdb, ntsd, kd, ntkd, and WinDbg.

---

As an aside: More generally, all Windows 10 developer "kits," including the Windows SDK, Windows Driver Kit, Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit, and others, are located at:

- 32-bit systems: `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10`
- 64-bit systems: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`

The Windows SDK installer places a shortcut to the above folder at this path in your Start Menu hierarchy:

`\Windows Kits\Windows Software Development Kit\Windows Software Development Kit`

(Windows 10 appears to flatten one level of this Start Menu subfolder hierarchy, so it appears instead as `\Windows Kits\Windows Software Development Kit`. But you can just search for "windows software development kit" and find it that way on any recent version of Windows.)